# Large scale regression using GPML with single input

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, regression

I use GPML Matlab package for a 2-d large scale regression problem.
As stated in the user manual (http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/code/matlab/doc/) I induce inputs for large scale regression.

`nu = fix(n/2); iu = randperm(n); iu = iu(1:nu); u = x(iu,:);`

where n is the number of input variables.

It works fine if I have more than 2 inputs. But the inference method fails when I want to compute predictions for only one input i.e. n= 1

```
covfunc = @covSEiso;
likfunc = @likGauss;
n= 1;
nu = fix(n/2); 
iu = randperm(n);
iu = iu(1:nu);
u = X(iu,:);
meanfunc = @meanConst;
covfuncF = {@covFITC, {covfunc}, u};
ll = 1.0; sf = 1.0; 
hyp.cov = log([ll sf]);
sn = 0.1;  hyp.lik = log(sn);
hyp.mean = 0;
[mF s2F] = gp(hyp, @infFITC, [], covfuncF, likfunc, X(:,2), Y, X(:,2));
```

I want to use only the second coloumn of X as my input to GP and perform training with target Y.

Comment: How do you mean fail? Do you receive an error?

Comment: @noumenal:  The following was the error message: ** Inference method failed [Error using covFITC (line 21)
Dimensionality of inducing inputs must match training inputs]**

Comment: Have you tried the command `edit covFITC` and look at line 21? I don't suggest you change this file, but maybe it will give you an idea about what causes the error. Where do you define the training inputs?

Comment: The last line of the code shows the training input which is all rows of X in coloumn 2 and I use the same for test. Y is my target value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the bug!

If I am using only 2 variables of X for training the model, the induced points should also be sampled for the same. 
But the bug is, I use induced points of X (which is 10 dimensional),

```
u = X(iu,:);
```

Which is wrong!
@noumenal : Looking at line 21 helped !Thanks